# Search a bunch of XML documents for a single term

Tags: php, xml

I need to search through a high number of XML documents for single terms (words from dictionary) that appear inside XML tags (at any level) and count them up to provide a frequency table for each term. I am using PHP5 and I'm going to run this on a local machine so time and performance hit isn't an issue - it can take a few days if required.

Comment: This is not really a question. What do you want to know? How were you planning to do it? Is a plaintext search good enough or do you need to parse the actual XML. How many files and how many terms are we talking about? Is it an option to inject all these documents in an existing search engine like Apache Lucene?

Comment: Guidance is what I am looking for. I am open as to how to do it. A plain text search will be fine. I just need to capture word counts. There are probably in excess of 50,000 XML documents. I need to search the repository for "aardvark", count the occurrences, then
"aardvarks", count the occurrences, then "aardwolf", count the occurrences etc. Ideally looking for a suitable PHP library or script. My Apache knowledge is weak.

Comment: Ok, that's clear. Thanks. Plaintext searching is easiest but a bit dangerous. The word: "item" for instance, will probably clash with the XML structure. Is this a one-time search or do you want these statistics for more than one dictionary/word-list?

Comment: I'll probably be running the search every six to twelve months, so fairly infrequently.

Comment: Have you considered using Zorba to allow you leverage its' xQuery processing?

You also have the option of going down the xml database route.

Also, you could use postgreSQL's XML data type to allow you run an XPATH against the xml but I've only cursarily investigated that option.